# Como converter datetime em data abreviada modelo brasileiro

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho um objeto `JSON` que me retorna um atributo `datetime`. Porém, gostaria de exibir ele em formato abreviado brasileiro. Exemplo **24 JUN 2014**.

**Atributo JSON :**

```
data {
    date: "2014-06-16 21:56:29"
}
```

Teria como fazer isso manipulando string, mas isso parece ser muito "gambiarra". Alguém sabe como melhor fazer isso? Lembrando que uso JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
function dataFormatada(d) {
    var nomeMeses = ['JAN', 'FEV', 'MAR', 'ABR', 'MAI', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AGO', 'SET', 'OUT', 'NOV', 'DEC']
    var data = new Date(d);
    var dia = data.getDate();
    var mes = data.getMonth();
    mes = nomeMeses[mes];
    var ano = data.getFullYear();
    return [dia, mes, ano].join(' ');
}

var json = {
    data: {
        date: "2014-06-16 21:56:29"
    }
}

var data = dataFormatada(json.data.date);
alert(data); // dá 16 JUN 2014
```

**Exemplo online:** http://jsfiddle.net/L7WGQ/

O código acima cria uma função que recebe uma string como a do seu exemplo e retorna outra string com o formato que pretende.

Os passos internos são mais ou menos evidentes. Talvez seja interessante referir que o `.getMonth()` retorna um numero começando em `0`. Ou seja, no caso de "janeiro" o valor seria `0`. Daí ser possivel usar diretamente como index da array que está no inicio da função onde estão guardadas as abreviaturas dos meses em do ano.

Se quiser mudar para letras pequenas pode usar o `.toLowerCase()`, mas como pediu na pergunta com letra grande, fiz assim.

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente, porém ao testar em navegadores diferente do Google Chrome ele apresenta um comportamento estranho. O seu retorno é "NaN NaN". Pode me ajudar com isso?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar os métodos do objeto [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) do JavaScript para fazer isso. Veja:

```
var data = {
    date: "2014-06-16 21:56:29"
};

var date = new Date(data.date),
    day = date.getDate(),
    month = date.getMonth(),
    year = date.getFullYear(),
    monthNames = ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'];

alert(day + ' de ' + monthNames[date.getMonth()] + ' de ' + year);
```

Para testar, preparei [este jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfyrT/) para você.

#### Explicação

`day`, `month` e `year` são variáveis onde ficarão armazenadas os números das datas que você usa – estes números são pegos através dos respectivos métodos `getDate()`, `getMonth()` e `getFullYear()` que o próprio JavaScript provém.

No `alert()`, estou usando `monthNames[date.getMonth()]` porque `date.getMonth()` retorna os meses no formato americano e ele segue o fluxo de indexação dos nomes dos meses utilizados no vetor `monthNames`, portanto, ambos coincidem.

Answer (score 4):

Você também pode deixar o javascript determinar qual o melhor formato

```
data = new Date("2014-06-16 21:56:29");

alert(data.toLocaleString());

//no navegador pt-BR vai dizer 16/6/2014 21:56:29
```

Answer (score 3):

Tem uma biblioteca muito boa, [Momentjs](http://momentjs.com/), que possui essa finalidade de conversão de datas para diversos tipos.

***Código:***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.6.0/moment-with-langs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#data").html(moment("2014-06-16 21:56:29").format("DD MMM YYYY"));
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="data"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Exemplo:*** [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hu7Ug/)

Comment: Diferente das outras respostas a sua funciona em mais Browsers. Se o MomentjS deixasse colocar o toUpperCase() no Month seria perfeito. Mas valeu! \õ

Comment: @PhellipeLins você quer deixar o mês em maiúsculo: http://jsfiddle.net/MMH2p/ igual nesse link de exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais fácil atualmente é utilizando o `Date.toLocaleString()` essa função permite exibir qualquer parte de uma data no formato que quiser, no idioma que quiser.

No seu caso seria dessa forma:

```js
var date = new Date("2014-06-16 21:56:29");
console.log(date.toLocaleString('pt', {day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric'}));

// Ou
console.log(date.getDate(), date.toLocaleString('pt', {month: 'short'}), date.getFullYear());
```

Assim é possivel exibir a data sem ficar criando Arrays gigantescos no código e sem utilizar nenhum framework externa