# Como pegar Data no formato dia, mês, ano e hora com JQuery

Tags: jquery, data, formatação

Tenho um trecho de código que consigo pegar a data e hora, mas a data fica no formato `Mês/Dia/Ano` seguido da hora, mas preciso no formato `Dia/Mês/Ano` seguido da hora, já tentei alterar a forma mas ficou incorreto, vejam o que tenho:

```
Number.prototype.padLeft = function(base,chr){
    var  len = (String(base || 10).length - String(this).length)+1;
    return len > 0? new Array(len).join(chr || '0')+this : this;
}

// Exibindo data no input ao iniciar tarefa
var d = new Date,
    dformat = [ (d.getMonth()+1).padLeft(),
                d.getDate().padLeft(),
                d.getFullYear()
              ].join('-') +
              ' ' +
              [ d.getHours().padLeft(),
                d.getMinutes().padLeft(),
                d.getSeconds().padLeft()
              ].join(':');
```

Nota: o formato inicial é um *timestamp*.

Comment: Não é só trocar `(d.getMont()+1).padLeft()` com `d.getDate().padLeft()`, não?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22369/129

Comment: Olá @Felipe Avelar, fiz isso, mas ai me aparece o seguinte: 04-2015 10:03:21, o dia não aparece.

Comment: @adventistapr, cara eu troquei aqui os dois e funcionou normal. Tenta colocar `[d.getDate().padLeft(), (d.getMont()+1).padLeft(),...` no primeiro vetor e vê se resolve o seu problema...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se o que tens inicialmente é um `timestamp` podes converter usando esta função:

```
function dataFormatada(d) {
    var data = new Date(d),
        dia  = data.getDate(),
        mes  = data.getMonth() + 1,
        ano  = data.getFullYear();
    return [dia, mes, ano].join('/');
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
function dataFormatada(d) {
  var data = new Date(d),
    dia = data.getDate(),
    mes = data.getMonth() + 1,
    ano = data.getFullYear();
  return [dia, mes, ano].join('/');
}

alert(dataFormatada(1382086394000));
```

Se quiseres usar também horas, minutos e segundos podes usar assim:

```
function dataFormatada(d) {
    var data = new Date(d),
        dia = data.getDate(),
        mes = data.getMonth() + 1,
        ano = data.getFullYear(),
        hora = data.getHours(),
        minutos = data.getMinutes(),
        segundos = data.getSeconds();
    return [dia, mes, ano].join('/') + ' ' + [hora, minutos, segundos].join(':');
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xt53v7hj/

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolvendo da seguinte forma, seguindo uma sugestão,

```
// Exibindo data no input ao iniciar tarefa
var d = new Date();
dataHora = (d.toLocaleString());    
// alert(d.toLocaleString());

// Mostrando data no campo
$('#DataInicio').val();
$('#DataInicio').val(dataHora);
```

A data exibida em meu input ficou assim:

```
08/04/2015 10:53:15
```

Comment: Mas assim o formato ficou `Dia/Mês/Ano HH:MM:SS` e não `Dia/Mês/Ano` como pedias na pergunta...

Comment: Olá @Sergio, verdade, cometi um erro na formulação da pergunta, comentei que precisava no formato Dia/Mês/Ano juntamente com a data.